# Unable to install or use any plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

My problem is that it's not possible to install any plugin in my QGIS 2.18. When I install it I get this error:

```
Couldn't load plugin 'quick_map_services' 
ImportError: No module named quick_map_services 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 308, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named quick_map_services
```

Here is QuickMapServices in example. But it behaves the same way with any other plugin from reposotory.

Besides Python 2.7 which is included into QGIS package I have Python 3.6 also...

How to make it working properly?

Comment: Please present error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Comment: 1. How do you start QGIS? You always should use the link/batchfile provided, because it does some configurations, especially for python. 2. Do you have a .qgis2 folder under the Windows-User-Path (generally C.\Users\yourusername), check, if qgis downloaded the plugin there (.qgis2\python\plugins).